# How do I print a char inside of an " if " in C

Tags: c, string, char, printf

So I have this part of code inside the main function:

```
    char causatxt[10];
    if(causa == CCOLA){
        causatxt[0] = "COLA";
    }
    else if(causa == CMURO){
        causatxt[0] = "CHOQUE";
    }

    printf("\n\nEl juego ha acabado por un '%s' con los siguientes datos:", causatxt);
```

The problem is that I want to print the sting in `causatxt`but if I define char inside the `if` I get a non defined error and if I do what I've pasted here I can't get `causatxt` to be either "COLA" or "CHOQUE".

I'm trying to avoid using a for loop to add the characters to every position of the array so I don't know if I'm supposed to use pointers because I'm not that experienced with those, but if using a for loop is the way to go then I guess I'll do that.

Thanks!

Comment: In C you can't copy a string like that. Please do `strcpy(causatxt, "COLA");`

Comment: `causatxt[0] = "COLA";` - `[0]` is for a character and you are assigning a string to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use strcpy from the string.h library

```
#include <string.h>
char a[100];
strcpy(a,"test");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if I understand correctly, you are experiencing a problem with setting a char* or char[] variable, that does not depend on if statement though.
If you want changeable text, I would rather use char* type. So you would write:

```
char* causatxt;
if(smth)
{
    causatxt = "COLA"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to copt the strings.

```
char causatxt[10];
if(causa == CCOLA){
    strcpy(causatxt,"COLA");
}
else if(causa == CMURO){
    strcpy(causatxt, "CHOQUE");
}
```